# Sentinel-2B API download

Tags: remote-sensing, api, sentinel-2

I tried downloading Sentinel-2B imagery from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s2b with python `urrlib2` but get `HTTPError: Unauthorized` on `urllib2.open()`.

The same procedure works for https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus (where S2B is not available).

Does anyone have a working method for programmatically downloading S2B?

Comment: Have you logged in using s2bguest/s2bguest?

Comment: yes. https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s2b/ ... s2bguest//s2bguest

Comment: Using api.download_all(products) returns the complete tile, instead of the map.geojson area only. How do you downloadd only the map.geojson?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158379)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you also raised this question as an [issue](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/145) at the [`sentinelsat`](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat) respository here is an example using `sentinelsat`.

```python
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson,geojson_to_wkt

api = SentinelAPI(user="s2bguest", password="s2bguest", api_url="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s2b")
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('map.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint, initial_date='NOW-10DAY')
```

Or once the data is merged into the Open Access Hub you can specifically query by `platformserialidentifier`:

```python
api = SentinelAPI(user="username", password="password", api_url="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus")
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('map.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint, initial_date='NOW-10DAY', platformserialidentifier="Sentinel-2B")
```

Comment: i hab a typo in my own script and seeing your answer work made me look harder :) I got it now. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also download S-2 products from [AWS](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/), which has better download speed than scihub.

Here is a python package that automatically downloads products into .SAFE format: https://github.com/sinergise/sentinelhub 
It works for S2A and S2B products.